# Is it possible to view the Photo gallery and Camera in the Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, video, camera, gallery

I'm new to iPhone development. I'm trying to develop a camera based app in the landscape mode.
I edited my info.plist supported orientations and the Interface Builder to the landscape mode. So at first my app prompt the user to chose a video from the gallery or to shoot a video. But both the video gallery and the camera view is in the Portrait mode.

Is there any way to make it landscape. I searched a lot but didn't find any answer. Can any on help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Means it is possible only in the portrait mode?

Comment: If you are using `UIImagePickerController`, you are bound to portrait mode as documentation states. You can write your own gallery using `ALAssetsLibrary`

Comment: How about the camera? Can we change it to Landscape mode?

Answer (score -1):

You can show the `UIImagePicker` in landscape mode, for that you need to subclass it and implement the `shouldAutoRotate` method to `return NO`.

```
@interface LandScapeUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

#import "LandScapeUIImagePickerController.h"

@interface LandScapeUIImagePickerController ()

@end

@implementation LandScapeUIImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Create the object of `LandScapeUIImagePickerController` instead of `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: Thank you Midhun. For me its working perfectly in the simulator but in the device the image picker is still showing in the portrait mode.

Comment: @Augustine: thanks for the comment. I don't know why it is not working on the device !

Comment: @Augustine: you need to set the rootviewcontroller of window

Comment: @DmitryKhryukin: I answered this question for iOS 6, in later version possibly apple changed something in that class.